# Is it possible to generate resource id for downloaded images in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am downloaded images from internet, is it possible to generate resource id for downloaded images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Resource IDs work only for resources packaged with the rest of the application in the .apk file. You'll have to use other I/O methods to access the images. You can save the images using [`Environment.getExternalStorateDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to obtain a `File` for the directory and then you can save and later read the image using normal file I/O operations.

Answer (score 3):

No, It is not possible. Resource id are allocated by System to the files that are added with the apk. It cannot be used for any external files.

Answer (score 3):

By Resource ID I assume you mean an R.*.* ID. This is not possible, as the R.java class is generated by the compiler when you compile your app. To use an image you've downloaded from the internet, you'll have to use the standard Java IO.